matrices with entries in a division ring is simple
I want to proof that matrices with entries in a division ring is simple.
From the website, I find that left ideal of $M_n(D)$ is bijection to the D submodule of $D^n$, where D is division ring, so my problem transfer to show that $D^n$ is left artinina, can someone help me? thanks

Considering that each subspace has to have dimension $\leq n$, how deep could your chain ever get?  But also, you said you want to prove it is simple.  You know that this condition is independent of being Artinian, right?  This particular ring is Artinian, but so are lots of other rings which aren't simple.  Anyhow, your title question and the first question in the post are well-answered on the site already.
